# Sockets not understood

Tags: android, kotlin

What I am trying to make is a local chat app (i.e, over local network, i.e. without internet only i.e. hotspot wifi based on android).I studied about sockets and tried to implement using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java I tried to make use of mainly `socket.emit` and `socket.on`. Both of my devices are connected on local network so can I do this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{


var TAG = "TCPClient"; //For debugging, always a good idea to have defined
var serverIp = "192.168.0.102";
var startTime = 0L;
var serverPort = 5000;
lateinit var socket:Socket
var onMessageReceived=object:Emitter.Listener
{
    override fun call(vararg args: Any?)
    {
        runOnUiThread {
            editText2.setText(args[0].toString())
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var SOCKET_URL="http://192.168.0.102"
    socket= IO.socket(SOCKET_URL)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        socket.emit("messageSent",editText.text.toString())
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    socket.on("messageSent",onMessageReceived)
    socket.connect()
}

override fun onDestroy()
{
    socket.disconnect()
    super.onDestroy()

}
```

}

What I was trying whatever is the text written in editext1(in one phone with ip 192.68.0.102) is displayed in edittex2 (of both devices (one with ip 192.168.0.102 and the other devices on local network(192.168.0.100) since I ran the same app on both devices)) when button is pressed.What I am doing wrong? I would have made this app by hosting rest service on one of the devices and accessing it from all the connected devices in the network but the main problem I was facing is that if I do so I would have to request the rest api again and again in a loop in a thread to check for a new message.

Don't all the connected devices listen when we use socket.on?

Comment: Check this simple example if you are trying to implement chat over local network: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/android-socket-messaging

Comment: Hey @NabinBhandari I didn't understand how were you able to receive message as soon as client sends a message by pressing the send button or vice versa by just using Buffered Reader?

Comment: why message never became null?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: `message` never became null because the line `String message = in.readLine();` waits until a message is received. But it becomes null when the connection is terminated.

Comment: ohhh kkk thanks sir :)

Comment: @NabinBhandari Sir I implemented and got succesfull in doing so.But still I would like to ask why emit and on are not working?:-)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about socket.io.

Comment: ok sir! Still thanks alot :)